# How to display 3d shapes with Processing 3

Tags: processing

I'm new to Processing 3 and I would like to display some 3d shapes. Here's what I've done so far:

```
void setup() {
  size(600,600,P3D);
}


void draw() {
  sphere(200);
}
```

and I got this error message :

> realloc(): invalid old size
>   Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).
>   For more information, read revisions.txt and Help → Troubleshooting.

Comment: This problem seems to been reported a lot and relates to Nvidia. https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/20470/processing-sketches-suddenly-not-running